# Thunderbird's CardDAV Address book is not syncing Google Contacts with labels in 2023

Tags: sync, thunderbird, address-book, google-contacts, carddav

Thunderbird (v.102 and surrounding) has a wonderful feature - It supports a Google Contacts Address Book synced via CardDAV. This works without any add-ons.

The problem I have is that **it only synchronizes contacts without labels**. Any contact with a label on Google's side is not copied into the Thunderbird.

Doesn't the Thunderbird's address book support the labels? What should I do to get all the contacts synced (apart of deleting all my labels)?

Comment: This is a known limitations. Try [TbSync](https://addons.thunderbird.net/fr/thunderbird/addon/tbsync/) and [CardBook](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/cardbook/).

Comment: @harrymc Maybe you can make this an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitations of CardDAV, not supporting labels.

Alternatives to CardDAV :

- [TbSync](https://addons.thunderbird.net/fr/thunderbird/addon/tbsync/)
- [CardBook](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/cardbook/).